# Change the design of DataTemplate of ListBox by programmatically in Windows Phone 8 App?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm binding message list to WPF listbox which are read and unread, I can bind it but I want the font weight of unread message to be bold and read message to be light.

My code looks like this

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Table}" x:Name="lbMessageList" >
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel  Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="460" >
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"Text="{Binding MessageSubject}"> 
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListBox>
```

I'm binding this data using

```
List<Table> myData = new List<Table>();
myData.Add(new Table() {MessageSubject = blog.MessageSubject });
```

Comment: Your items should have property, to example `bool IsMessageRead`. Then you can use this property to change something in single `DataTemplate` (you don't need more). Easiest is to create converter, which return [normal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontweights.aspx) font on `false` and bold on `true` and bind to [`TextBlock.FontWeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontweight.aspx)

Comment: Change your tag, Windows Phone 8 is very different to wpf.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `MessageRead` boolean flag in your `Table` class. Bind `FontWeight` on the `TextBlock` element to `MessageRead` and use a `Converter` to convert `false` to `Bold` and `true` to `Normal`/`Light`.

Comment: @Toadflaks i haven't getting the **<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"Text="{Binding MessageSubject}">** Id in code behing, so how can i decide   the TextBlock will be bold this time and light this time,,,it's Confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this DataTemplate :

```
<DataTemplate >
    <StackPanel  Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="460" >
        <TextBlock Name="txtMessageHeader" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MessageSubject}">
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ReadStatusOfMessage}" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="txtMessageHeader" Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: it throws an error----Error 2 The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'DataTemplate'.

Comment: Yes it's possible, can't accept code and error is ->the member triggers is not recognized or is not accessible, i'm using above code in my <ListBox>code</ListBox>